# searching if an item is in a list of objects

Tags: python, list, object, oop

I am trying to ask a user for a username and password and check a file with user name and passwords to see if it exists if it does it just says welcome if it doesnt tells the user he put in the wrong info. The file is just a simple text file with format "username,password" as shown below

SSD,adgEgd

aegag,asdhasdh

here is my code

```
class Account():
    def __init__(self, name, password):
        self.name = name
        self.password = password

username_input = input("Enter the name: ")
userpassword_input = input("Enter password: ")
file = open('account information.txt', 'r')

data = []
for lines in file:
    temp = lines.split(',')
    data.append(Account(temp[0], temp[1]))
file.close()
isExsits = ' '
for d in data:
    if username_input == d.name and userpassword_input == d.password:
        isExsits = 'huzzah'          
print(isExsits)
```

It identifies the username but not the password

Comment: How do you know it works for one and not the other? You can add some debugging lines, similar to your `if` statement - `print("actual='{}'\nuserpw='{}'\n\tmatch? {}".format(userpassword_input, d.password, userpassword_input == d.password)` for instance and see exactly why the two are not lining up, or if there is a logic issue elsewhere.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please try to [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) the code and communicate your findings clearly. For example, how do you know that "it identifies the username but not the password" - what specifically about the results suggests that to you? Did you try separately checking the result from `username_input == d.name` and `userpassword_input == d.password`? Then you should 1) **show that**, and 2) try to diagnose the problem. For example, is `d.password` what you expect it to be?

Comment: It also helps to try to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For example, do you need to read from a file in order to cause the problem? What if you had used a hard-coded list of lines for your `file`?

Answer (score 0):

There is a newline character in the password and it looks like adgEgd\n after reading from file.

You can get rid from it by using `rstrip`

`data.append(Account(temp[0], temp[1].rstrip()))`

Answer (score 0):

It seems to working fine like this, so I would likewise say it's probably the newlines or other extraneous characters at the end of the lines that are throwing off the calculation.

```py
user_pass_list = [
    ('SSD', 'adgEgd'),
    ('aegag', 'asdhasdh')
]

username = 'SSD'
password = 'adgEgd'
exists = False

for d in user_pass_list:
    if username == d[0] and password == d[1]:
        exists = True

print(exists)  # True
```

Another approach can be to just do an `in` check, so that we don't need to iterate over `user_pass_list` for example:

```py
user_pass_list = [
    ('SSD', 'adgEgd'),
    ('aegag', 'asdhasdh')
]

username = 'SSD'
password = 'adgegd' # casing is different

exists = (username, password) in user_pass_list

assert exists is False  # True
```

With the `Account` class example from the original question, reformatted as a [dataclass](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) for slightly cleaner code:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass


# same as `@dataclass(eq=True)`, so an equals (__eq__) method
# is automatically generated for the class.
@dataclass
class Account:
    name: str
    password: str


user_pass_list = [
    Account('SSD', 'adgEgd'),
    Account('aegag', 'asdhasdh')
]

username = 'SSD'
password = 'adgEgd'

exists = Account(username, password) in user_pass_list

assert exists is True  # True
```

Answer (score 0):

This works as you intended, it iterates over all accounts in the `account_information.txt` file and creates an `Account` object for each of them which is added to the `data` list.

Afterwards, we iterate through every account and check to see if the credentials provided by the user match any within the list.

```py
class Account():
    def __init__(self, name, password):
        self.name = name
        self.password = password

username_input = input("Enter the name: ")
userpassword_input = input("Enter password: ")

data = []
with open("account_information.txt") as file:
    for line in file.readlines():
        credentials = line.rstrip().split(",")
        data.append(Account(credentials[0], credentials[1]))

accountExists = False
for account in data:
    if (account.name == username_input) and (account.password == userpassword_input):
        accountExists = True

print(accountExists)
```